# Using angular i18n on conditional operators (ternary)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-i18n

Is it possible to use i18n on strings that require conditional operation

```html
<h2 i18n>{{ updateMode ? 'Edit' : 'Add'}}</h2>
```

Comment: Have you tried it out? I mean if you already use angulars i18n mechanism, then you probably can test this in 1 minute. (I use ngx-translate instead, so I cannot answer your question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<h2 i18n>{{ updateMode ? 'Edit' : 'Add'}}</h2>
```

In your .xlf file you will get something like this

```
<source>
  <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{updateMode  ? 'Edit': 'Add'}}"/>
</source>
```

Target should look like this:

```
<target>
  {{updateMode  ? 'TranslatedValue1' : 'TranslatedValue2'}}
</target>
```

**EDIT:** This answer is not relevant since angular v.9.0
You can not use ternary operator anymore, instead it use:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="updateMode" i18n="@@translationID1>TranslatedValue1</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!updateMode" i18n="@@translationID2>TranslatedValue2</ng-container>
```

Comment: I get an error: Unable to parse ICU expression in "{{loading ? 'Loading Module...' : 'Log In'}}" message.